# What is meaning/difference of Level 2 and Level 1 in XMLHttpRequest provided by W3C

Tags: xmlhttprequest, specifications, w3c

What is meaning/difference of Level 2 and Level 1 in XMLHttpRequest document provided by W3C

what is that Level No represents in that W3c provided document?

[XMLHttpRequest Level1](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a specification is developed at W3C, multiple major revisions of different maturity can exist simultaneously. So for example Level 1 could be the more mature version (closer to becoming a Recommendation), and Level 2 might define more features, but be further away from becoming a REC.

---

In the specific case of XHR (based on the ["Specification history" section of the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#specification-history)):

- The XMLHttpRequest object was initially defined as part of the **[WHATWG](https://whatwg.org/faq#what-is-the-whatwg)’s HTML** specification.
- **[W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)** was an attempt to push the description of the functionality already implemented by MS Internet Explorer (and copied by other browsers) through the [W3C Process](https://www.w3.org/2017/Process-20170301/#recs-and-notes), designed to:

  > - support multiple specification development methodologies
  > - maximize consensus about the content of stable technical reports
  > - ensure high technical and editorial quality
  > - promote consistency among specifications
  > - facilitate royalty-free, interoperable implementations of Web Standards, and
  >     earn endorsement by W3C and the broader community.
- Since the process of becoming a W3C recommendation is rather slow, most improvements that were yet to be implemented were defined in a separate document, **[W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/)**, which was intended to become a W3C Recommendation later than Level 1 and to eventually supersede the Level 1 version.
- At some point, the maintainers [found that the snapshot-based development approach didn't work very well](https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-are-there-no-stable-snapshots-or-versions-of-the-standard), decided to [abandon the attempt to publish the documents as W3C-endorsed recommendations](https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/master/FAQ.md#whats-this-i-hear-about-2022) and continued to develop a single specification, **[WHATWG XMLHttpRequest Living Standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)**.